# Publish wrapped OSGi bundles to artifactory with Gradle

Tags: gradle, osgi, artifactory

As not all jars are automatically usable OSGi bundles I use wrapping to generate them. After having being wrapped I'd like to publish them to my Artifactory repository. However, my lack of understanding of Gradle inhibits success, and after reading several suggested Stackoverflow answers I am still stuck.

This is my build.gradle file:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://localhost:8081/artifactory/gradle-dev' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.standardout:bnd-platform:1.2.0'
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4+"
    }
    }

    apply plugin: 'org.standardout.bnd-platform'
    apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

    group = 'com.google.code.gson'
    version = '2.8.0' 

    publishing {
        publications {
            osgiBundles(MavenPublication) {
                artifacts {
            files("build/plugins")
            }
            }
        }
    }

    artifactory {
            contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"   //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver

        publish {
                repository {
                        repoKey = 'gradle-dev-local'
                        username = "${artifactory_user}"
                        password = "${artifactory_password}"
                        maven = true
                }

            defaults {
                publications ('osgiBundles')
            }

            }

        resolve {
                repository {
                        repoKey = 'gradle-dev'
                        username = "${artifactory_user}"
                        password = "${artifactory_password}"
                        maven = true
                }
            }

    }

platform {
    useBndHashQualifiers = false
    defaultQualifier = ''
        bundle(group: 'com.google.code.gson', name:'gson', version:'2.8.0') {
          bnd {
            instruction 'Export-Package', 'com.google.gson,com.google.gson.stream,com.google.gson.annotations,com.google.gson.reflect'
                  }
        }
}
```

The output of the script is as follows:

```
gradle artifactoryPublish
:generatePomFileForOsgiBundlesPublication
:artifactoryPublish
Deploying artifact: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/gradle-dev-local/com/google/code/gson/bundle-jars/2.8.0/bundle-jars-2.8.0.pom
Deploying build descriptor to: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/build
Build successfully deployed. Browse it in Artifactory under http://localhost:8081/artifactory/webapp/builds/bundle-jars/1489323863518
```

When I look in the artifactory repository the structure is not what I expected:

```
+- com
 +--- google/code/gson/bundle-jars
 |+-- 2.8.0
 | +- bundle-jars.pom
 +--- maven-metadata.xml
```

The wrong directory structure (google/code/gson/bundle-jars), where I expected several sub directorties (google, code, gson) with a 2.8.0 and a jar file.

I think I have to change the publications block, but I don't know what it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The publication should be as follows:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        osgiBundles(MavenPublication) {
        groupId 'my.group'
        artifactId 'com.google.code.gson'
        version '2.8.0'
        artifact file("build/plugins/com.google.code.gson_2.8.0.jar")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [unpuzzle](https://github.com/akhikhl/unpuzzle) (or rather [this fork](https://github.com/stempler/unpuzzle)) to create Maven artifacts from OSGi bundles (and publish them to Artifactory).

This is probably not the most efficient solution for your use case, but at least something that works and I can come up with fast.

[Here is an example](https://github.com/halestudio/hale/blob/0d2342f7c4d963e0f66027861e883f44ee10440e/build/gradle/deployArtifacts.gradle) of where I use unpuzzle for this purpose. Maybe that can serve as a starting point (together with the unpuzzle docs). There is a lot of bloat in my example because there I try to actually determine the original Maven artifacts for OSGi bundles created from them - as you always want the OSGi bundle, that's probably not relevant for you.

Note that by default the published artifacts will have different names (based on the bundle symbolic name) and a different group (which is configurable). But I think that is to be preferred over having the original group and name, otherwise it may get confused w/ the original. Adapting the group and name individually is possible as you can see in the example.